# Binary Search Tree Insert Function In C

Tags: c, struct, null, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

For future viewers of this question who might need help in this type of problem: I fixed it by combining the 2 functions (InsertNode() and InTree()) I'm not sure if this is bad practice and I'll get back to you guys with if it actually really does solve the problem or if it just masks it, but it seems to be working...

I've looked through various answers on this website (as well as others) and from those I've gotten solutions which didn't help (tried and didn't work or just didn't differ from my program).
The insert function (I've isolated it and think this is the problematic code) has some bug somewhere that causes my program to crash.

```
NP InTree(NP Node,NP Root)
{
    if (Root == NULL)
    {
        Root=Node;
        return Root;
    }
    else
    {
        if (Node->Input < Root->Input)
        {
            return InTree(Node,Root->Left);
        }
        else if (Node->Input > Root->Input)
        {
            return InTree(Node,Root->Right);
        }
        else
        {
            puts("Duplicate");
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}

void InsertNode(int I, TP Tree)
{

    NP Node;
    Node=(NP)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLNode));
    InitializeNode(Node);
    Node->Input=I;
    Node->Height=0;
    Node->Left=NULL;
    Node->Right=NULL;
    InTree(Node,Tree->Root);
    Tree->Size++;
}
```

NP is a Node Pointer, TP is a Tree Pointer

The Node variable is the initialized node sent through InsertNode()

```
void InitializeTree(TP Tree)
{

    Tree->Root=NULL;
    Tree->Size=0;
}

void InitializeNode(NP Node)
{

    Node->Input=0;
    Node->Height=0;
}
```

The above are my Initialize functions just in case you need to see them.

The memory for the Tree is allocated in the main class before any of the functions are called.

The main problem from what I saw through testing is that once Root is made equal to Node it remains null.

Any ideas how I can get past the problem?

Comment: null was used as a tag because my problem has something to do with a variable staying null

Comment: should've been more clear with that..
NP is a pointer to the Node struct
in code:
typedef Node*  NP;

Comment: I think basically you could try ``Root = new NodeStruct; Root->Input = Node->Input`` instead of directly ``Root = Node``. Try this version ``InTree(int v, NP Root)``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `InTree` function, where the `Root` is made equal to `Node`, it only changes the memory locally.

Instead, you may need to use a pointer to a pointer to achieve what you're trying.

Comment: It would be useful if you could post a solid code example describing your suggestion to support your answer.

Comment: It's ok I understood what he meant
It actually sounds like a pretty good idea

Comment: @EdwardBamber, don't forget to upvote and/or accept good answers!

Comment: Thing is I'm trying all of these answers but nothing's working :(

Answer (score 0):

`void InsertNode(int I, TP Tree)` allocates mem for a new node, but when you call `NP InTree(NP Node,NP Root)` you only modify the local pointer address.  You need to either use a pointer to a pointer (i.e. `NP InTree(NP Node, NP *ppRoot)`) or the following example:

```
if (Node->Input < Root->Input) {
    if(Root->Left == NULL) {
        Root->Left = Node;
    } else {
        return InTree(Node,Root->Left);
    }
} else if (Node->Input > Root->Input) {
    if(Root->Right== NULL) {
        Root->Right= Node;
    } else {
        return InTree(Node,Root->Right);
    }
} else {
    puts("Duplicate");
    return NULL;
}
```

Ps. I notice you allocate struct AVLNode...is NP a typedef of AVLNode (`typedef struct AVLNode* NP`)?  I don't know what your structures are so I can't say.  Technically AVLs are different from B-trees in that they are self balancing... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree

Comment: NP is exactly that, yes. I know, my plan is to create a BST and then add those self balancing conditions to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it something like this. Your insert function doesn't differentiate between the special case (an empty tree) and the general case (a non-empty tree).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct NODE
{
  struct NODE *left  ;
  struct NODE *right ;
  int          value ;
  int          depth ;
} NODE ;

typedef struct TREE
{
  NODE *root  ;
  int   count ;
} TREE ;

NODE *node_create( int value )
{
  NODE *instance = (NODE*) calloc( 1 , sizeof(NODE) ) ;
  instance->value = value ;
  return instance ;
}

TREE *tree_create()
{
  TREE *instance = (TREE*) calloc( 1 , sizeof(TREE) ) ;
  return instance ;
}

NODE *tree_find_and_insert( NODE *parent , int value )
{
  NODE *child = NULL ;

  if ( value < parent->value )
  {
    if ( parent->left == NULL )
    {
      child = node_create(value) ;
      child->depth = ++ parent->depth ;
      parent->left = child ;
      return child ;
    }
    else
    {
      return tree_find_and_insert(parent->left , value ) ;
    }
  }
  else if ( value > parent->value )
  {
    if ( parent->right == NULL )
    {
      child = node_create(value) ;
      child->depth = ++ parent->depth ;
      parent->right = child ;
      return child ;
    }
    else
    {
      return tree_find_and_insert( parent->right , value ) ;
    }
  }
  else /* ( value == parent->value ) */
  {
    // NO-OP by design: dupes fall out and NULL is returned
  }

  return child ;
}

NODE *tree_insert( TREE *tree , int value )
{
  NODE *inserted = NULL ;
  if ( tree->root == NULL )
  {
    tree->root  = node_create( value ) ;
    tree->count = 1 ;
    inserted = tree->root ;
  }
  else
  {
    inserted = tree_find_and_insert( tree->root , value ) ;
  }
  return inserted ;
}

int main ( int argc , char *argv[] )
{
  TREE *my_tree = tree_create() ;
  int i ;

  for ( i = 1 ; i < argc ; ++i )
  {
    char *arg = argv[i] ;
    int   n   = atoi(arg) ;

    tree_insert( my_tree , n ) ;

  }

  return 0 ;
}
```